# Solutions to Knowledge Issue

Tags: lightning, lightning-knowledge

I've formatted my Solutions articles to fit the Knowledge fields and rich-text fields, downloaded and enter the correct parameter for my .property file and I keep getting an error of:

The .properties file is missing.
 CSV file not found.

I don't have an HTML file because there are no photos with our articles. 
Any advice?